# Invoking your application from browser in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I would like my application to be associated with certain extension (in my case *.ecw).

The use case is that, when somebody clicks on a link in a browser (f.e. Internet Explorer) that directs to a *.ecw file (http://address.com/files/itscool.ewc), my application is launched and the whole information (nagivation context, file token etc.) is passed along.

*.ecw is a ASCII text file, so it can be viewed in the browser easily but I'd like to invoke my app when such URI/file is entered/launched. I need to process the data stored in the file and produce some output for the user.

So far I have "registered" (according to MSDN tutorial) the file association in the manifest:

```
<Extensions>
  <FileTypeAssociation Name="ECWReader" TaskID="_default" NavUriFragment="fileToken=%s">
    <SupportedFileTypes>
      <FileType ContentType="application/ecw">.ecw</FileType>
    </SupportedFileTypes>
  </FileTypeAssociation>
</Extensions>
```

But this didn't help at all - browser keeps opening those files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct. However, the reason why it doesn't work is that, while the extention of the file is .ewc, the content type that the server responds with when requesting that url is `text/html` and not `application/ecw`.

If the server responds with a ContentType `text/html`, it simply means that the response is intended to be read by a web browser, and not some other app.

Here's a [link to a ecw file](http://www.barrowdowns.com/crosswords/0003.ecw) that comes with a ContentType `of text/plain`. Change your ContentType filter to match it and try that link in your phone, it should normally work and your app will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have applied those changes, and even though the server returns `text/plain` (checked in Fiddler) it gets opened by Internet Explorer. Any other suggestions?